# How to make text on disabled textfield clear

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I created a form using extjs4 where there are some textfields. I wonder if is it possible to make the text inside the textfields more "black" or clear when the textfield is disabled? And if it is possible, how do I do it? I searched the api but I can't seem to find the answer. When it is disabled, I cant hardly read the text inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabled fields get the `x-item-disabled` class added (you can change it by passing [`disabledCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-disabledCls)).
You can change it in your theme (_core.scss) or css.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/8mjvg/1/

```
.x-item-disabled {
    .-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    .filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
}  

.x-item-disabled .x-form-field {
    color: red;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`disable`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-disable) & [`enable`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-enable) events to change the field style.